# draggable sets left to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal of the script is drag element but leave copy of the element.

```
function makeDraggable() {
    $('.col-md-4').addClass('is-draggable');
    $('.is-draggable').draggable({
        start: function(event, ui){
            if($(this).hasClass('not-draggable'))
            return;

            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(this).after(cl);
            var of = cl.offset();

            $(this).addClass('rect').offset({top:of.top,left:of.left}).css({width:cl.css('width'), height:cl.css('height')});
            makeDraggable();
            $(this).addClass('not-draggable');
        }
    });
}

makeDraggable();
```

When you mousedown on some boxes it clones box and then draggable placing this element to the left top corner and don't allow to set my own offset. I want the dragable element left on the same place and don't jump. Demo [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QmbG/17/)

Comment: You know that there is a JSFiddle option to include jQuery UI? I cleaned up your JSFiddle's formatting -> http://jsfiddle.net/9QmbG/18/ I have a feeling that your issue is the `position:absolute;` on your `.rect` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use offset because it's already used by the drag event. You can use margins to offset your draggable.

Also, use ui.helper to get the offset

```
var of = $(ui.helper).offset();

$(this).addClass('rect').css({'margin-top':of.top,'margin-left':of.left}).css({width:cl.css('width'), height:cl.css('height')});
```

## Demo

External JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9QmbG/22

```js
function makeDraggable() {
    $('.col-md-4').addClass('is-draggable');
    
    $('.is-draggable').draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            
            if ($this.hasClass('not-draggable')) return;

            var cl = $this.clone();
            $this.after(cl);
            var of = $(ui.helper).offset();

            $this.addClass('rect').css({
                'margin-top': of.top,
                'margin-left': of.left
            }).css({
                width: cl.css('width'),
                height: cl.css('height')
            });
            
            makeDraggable();
            $this.addClass('not-draggable');
        }
    });
}

makeDraggable();
```

```css
#score {
    height:50px;
}
.col-md-4 {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px 20px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.rect {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100000;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="score">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-4">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4">3</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Looks so much better. At first I thought it wasn't my answer.